# NaN error in function in R

Tags: r

The objective of my function is to calculated a truncated mean, i.e., you give a sample, and then compute the mean for all the values between certain quantiles.

To do that, I've written

```
 meank<-function(x,k){
  xt<-quantile(x,c(k,1-k));
  mean(x[x>xt[1] & x < xt[2] ])
}
```

When doing `meank(rnorm(100),0.4)`, it returns `NaN`. Why is that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well of course it does some time. The symmetric quantile cut off rule leaves only 20% of the range in the allowed values for further provessing, so when the random numbers do not hit that, you get NaN

Comment: @coffeinjunky thanks for your help. You're right. It's was a mistake of mine. I wrote 0.5 for the quantile, which would leave nothing... Sorry for your lost time. ;)

Comment: It was not lost! If only us making mistakes would be always so responsive and open minded :-) Thanks for the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the implementation of `meank` you cancel all values outside of `[k, 1-k]`"percent" of range, thus when no value is left in, the subsequent `mean`has to yield `NaN`.

Reproducible test:

```
> meank(c(1, 2, 2),0.4)
[1] NaN
```

Details step wise evaluation:

```
> quantile(c(1, 2, 2),c(0.4,1-0.4))
40% 60% 
1.8 2.0
```

and:

```
> xt <- quantile(c(1, 2, 2),c(0.4,1-0.4))
> mean(c(1, 2, 2)[c(1, 2, 2)>xt[1] & c(1, 2, 2) < xt[2] ])
[1] NaN
```

Comment: Well, a first step would be - I think - to simply store the rnorm(1000) then in a variable and use the summary etc helpers or simply dump it to look at the reason for this. Curious if there is a typo or a bad RNG ...

Comment: My bad! Sorry, I wrote 0.5 in the code. Many thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: You are welcome to accept my answer :-) Thanks - and it has been a very interesting problem and a good collaborative thanks to the OP and @coffeinjunky